# Problem with rsync files with spaces in folder name

Tags: unix, rsync

I'm trying to back up some files with rsync at the job. The problem I have is that one of the folders I'm about to back up has a space in it.

```
SOURCE=/Volumes/Annons Prod/Ad
TARGET=/Volumes/Backup/Annons Prod/Ad
TARGETDISK=/Volumes/Backup
```

I have tried it like this and with `/Volumes/Annons\ Prod/Ad` and `"/Volumes/Annons Prod/Ad"`but the sam result.

Rsync command:

```
time $RSYNC -eahfs -a -E -x -S -p -r -u --progress `find "$SOURCE" -type d -mtime -144h` "$TARGET" >>
```

Error message says: `rsync link_stat "/Volumes/Annons" failed, no such file or directory`

I'm doing this on a Mac and the file is a .sh.

Is there a way to get around this? We can't change the name of the directory...

Thanks

Comment: Show `rsync` command you use.

Comment: time $RSYNC -eahfs -a -E -x -S -p -r -u --progress 'find "$SOURCE" -type d -mtime -144h' "$TARGET" >>

Comment: Are these 2 commands?

Comment: no, one the editor here made something with it.

Comment: Post the *correct* command then.

Comment: That should be it

Comment: Should be what?

Comment: The rsync-command is edited now

Comment: Are you really sure you use `'find "$SOURCE" -type d -mtime -144h'` with single quotes `'` and not backticks or `$(`?

Comment: I guess it should be backticks and that's why it messed up the format when posting.

Comment: This discussion doesn't make any sense. Edit your question and post the correct command you used and explain what shell and OS you use.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping out.

Comment: The way the shell parses the output of a command in backticks is... unfortunate. Don't use it. See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) But is this really necessary? It looks like you're trying to achieve something that `rsync` itself could do with the right options. Speaking of which, the `rsync` options you are using look weird -- the string following `-e` doesn't make sense, and some other options are redundant (implied by `-a`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your command

```
time $RSYNC -eahfs -a -E -x -S -p -r -u --progress `find "$SOURCE" -type d -mtime -144h` "$TARGET" >>
```

doesn't work correctly is that output of `find "$SOURCE" -type d -mtime -144h` command substitution undergoes [word
splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). Your shell
treats each word separated by a whitespace as a separate argument to
`rsync`.  If you want to combine `rsync` with `find` you can the
technique described here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rsync however
version of `find` shipped with macOS most probably doesn't support
`-printf` option (I don't have access to macOS but tried it on
Freebsd). In this case the correct command should be something like
this:

```
cd "$SOURCE" && find . -type f -print0 | rsync -vn --files-from=- --from0 . "$TARGET" && cd - >/dev/null
```

Notice several things here:

1. It will work well with files containing special characters in their
   names including newlines as the list of files to be transferred fed to
   `rsync` will be separated by `\0` which is not allowed in the
   filename.
2. I didn't use exact find and rsync options you used, modify them to
   fit your needs but I suggest leaving `-n` option for testing.
3. The last `cd -` will go back the original directory and will print
   its name, I redirect it to `/dev/null` so that it won't bother us.

And finally, as someone already said in the comment, it's possible
that rsync can do what you want to do on its own. Consider reading
`man rsync` and look for examples online.